# How to run a PHP Script in TFS ?Is there anyway to run PHP Script through commandline in TFS?

Tags: php, tfs

When I'm trying to integrate the PHP Script in TFS, I could not see any option.
Currently I'm writing all my tests in PHP.I need to execute these scripts once the developers deploy their code.
FYI,The developers are writing their code in C#.
Do we have anyway to execute the php scripts through in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy a private build agent and setup the PHP runtime on the agent machine.

- See [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) for details, you can also
  reference this article : [How to setup a Private Agent in Visual
  Studio Team Services](https://ilclubdellesei.wordpress.com/2017/11/04/how-to-setup-a-private-agent-in-visual-studio-team-services/)

Then follow the steps/instructions mentioned in below article to set the build system to run the PHP tests.

- [Creating a build agent and definition for PHP in VSTS](https://hajekj.net/2016/10/30/creating-a-build-agent-and-definition-for-php-in-vsts/)